# Dead simple Fork-Join concurrency in Clojure

Tags: concurrency, clojure, future

I have two costly functions that are independent. I want to run them in parallel. I don't want to deal with futures and such (I'm new to Clojure and easily confused).

I'm looking for a simple way to run two functions concurrently. I want it to work like the following

```
(defn fn1 [input] ...) ; costly
(defn fn2 [input] ...) ; costly

(let [[out1 out2] (conc (fn1 x) (fn2 y))] ...)
```

I want this to return a vector with a pair of outputs. It should only return once both threads have terminated. Ideally conc should work for any number of inputs. I suspect this is a simple pattern.

Comment: When you say you don't want to deal with futures, does that mean you don't want futures to be used in the "conc" function either?  It is idiomatic to use one of the Clojure concurrency primitives in such as case, as far as I know, though they could be hidden from you via encapsulation in "conc."

Comment: Definitely some concurrency primitives will be used. conc can be as sophisticated as you like. I just don't want to deal with them as a user. I suspect this is "start a future for each input", "wait on each output", "return". Maybe it will have to be a macro, not sure.

Comment: Definitely a macro if you want to defer evaluations of the arguments to conc to the threads.  I'm working on the macro def'n now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need a macro to preserve the desired syntax, though there are other ways of obtaining the same behavior, as the other answers indicate.  Here is one way to do it:

```
(defn f1 [x] (Thread/sleep 500) 5)
(defn f2 [y] 2)

(defmacro conc [& exprs]
  `(map deref
        [~@(for [x# exprs] `(future ~x#))]))

(time (let [[a b] (conc (f1 6) (f2 7))]
       [a b]))
; "Elapsed time: 500.951 msecs"
;= (5 2)
```

The expansion shows how it works:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(conc (f1 6) (f2 7)))
;= (clojure.core/map clojure.core/deref [(clojure.core/future (f1 6)) 
;=                                       (clojure.core/future (f2 7))])
```

You specified two functions but this should work with any number of expressions.

Comment: Awesome. This inspired me to try it out on my own. I tried to make it  by replacing the for with `(map future exprs)`. Sadly this didn't work because future is itself a macro. Any thoughts on how this could be reduced even further?

Comment: Yeah, that's the trouble w/ macros -- can't compose them as easily as functions.  I don't know how to reduce it further, but someone on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/clojure) might.

Answer (score 4):

Using futures is very easy in Clojure. At any rate, here is an answer that avoids them

```
(defn conc [& fns]
  (doall (pmap (fn [f] (f)) fns)))
```

`pmap` uses futures under the hood. `doall` will force the sequence to evaluate.

```
(let [[out1 out2] (conc fn1 fn2)]
        [out1 out2])
```

Note, that I destructured `out1` and `out2` in an attempt to preserve your example.

Comment: to use this you need to wrap your inputs in anonymous functions ie: #(fn1 42)

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt correct, in which case I would go with JohnJ's solution.

Comment: and I think not wrapping it in a a macro leads to better composable code. Macros are not first class things, you can't pass them to map or apply them to lists of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you don't want your final solution to expose futures though it is useful to illustrate how to do this with futures, and then wrap them in something that hides this detail:

```
core> (defn fn1 [input] (java.lang.Thread/sleep 2000) (inc input))
#'core/fn1                                                                                     
core> (defn fn2 [input] (java.lang.Thread/sleep 3000) (* 2 input))
#'core/fn2                                                                                     
core> (time (let [f1 (future (fn1 4)) f2 (future (fn2 4))] @f1 @f2))
"Elapsed time: 3000.791021 msecs"
```

then we can wrap that up in any of the many clojure wrappers around futures. the simplest being just a function which takes two functions and runs them in parallel.

```
core> (defn conc [fn1 fn2] 
         (let [f1 (future (fn1)) 
               f2 (future (fn2))] [@f1 @f2]))
#'core/conc                                                                                    
core> (time (conc #(fn1 4) #(fn2 4)))
"Elapsed time: 3001.197634 msecs"
```

This avoids the need to write it as a macro by having conc take the function to run instead of the body to evaluate, and then create the functions to pass to it by putting `#` infront of the calls.

This can also be written with map and future-call:

```
core> (map deref (map future-call [#(fn1 4) #(fn2 42)]))
(5 84)
```

You can then improce conc until it resembles (as Julien Chastang wisely points out) `pmap`